# Can a abstract class include non-abstract class parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from the aritcle https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

In my mind, a abstract class can not include non-abstract class .

But the function `abstract fun bindAnalyticsService( analyticsServiceImpl: AnalyticsServiceImpl): AnalyticsService` accept a non-abstract class parameter, why?

**Code A**

```
interface AnalyticsService {
  fun analyticsMethods()
}

// Constructor-injected, because Hilt needs to know how to
// provide instances of AnalyticsServiceImpl, too.
class AnalyticsServiceImpl @Inject constructor(
  ...
) : AnalyticsService { ... }

@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class AnalyticsModule {

  @Binds
  abstract fun bindAnalyticsService(
    analyticsServiceImpl: AnalyticsServiceImpl
  ): AnalyticsService
}
```

Comment: "In my mind, a abstract class can not include non-abstract class." Why？

Comment: *"But the function [...] accept a non-abstract class parameter, why?"* Why not?

Comment: I'm unsure of the term "non-abstract class parameter" in reference to a function. Could you explain this a bit more? Every function's parameters are abstract because they can accept any argument conforming to the parameter type. Abstract classes are a stateful interface; as far as I am aware, nothing is ever required to be abstract except for the functions and values of an abstract class itself.

Comment: In my mind, a  abstract class can only accept other  abstract class or interface as parameter.

Comment: What made you think so?

Comment: Abstract means the class isn't 100% complete. It doesn't mean the class is 0% complete. It would be pointless for there to even be abstract classes if you couldn't define *any*thing concrete in them, and not even use classes like Int or String in them!